# Detect user's watchOS version from iOS app

Tags: ios, swift, apple-watch, watchos

I have an iOS app where I have some settings in the iOS app related to the watch. I only want to show them if the user has an Apple Watch that's compatible with my app.

In WatchConnectivity I can query WCSession's isPaired property to see if the user has a watch but I can't figure out how to determine the watchOS version (it needs to be >5.0 to use my app).

Is there a way to determine the watchOS version from the iOS app?

Comment: I do not think you can check the watchOS version from iOS. However, you could communicate between the watch app from iOS app to get information you need.

Comment: Thanks but I'm still not able to tell the difference between a user who has a watch on watchOS 4 and can't install the watch app vs a user on watchOS 5 that can install the watch app but hasn't

Comment: @Stephen try to get from bluetooth info you are interested in [Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51456455/4261814) [Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51147824/4261814)

Comment: interesting idea, unfortunately the watch seems to have special handling where it's not available through the standard bluetooth methods

Comment: Why don't you just restrict the watchOS ```Deployment Target``` to be 5.0 ?

Comment: That is the restriction. I have watch specific settings I want to show in my iOS app. I want to hide them if the user has watchOS 4 but I have no way of knowing if they can install the app successfully or not

Comment: This doesn't seem to be possible so I've submitted feedback to Apple: FB7534158

Answer (score 2):

If the settings only apply if the user has your watch app installed, you probably just want to check that directly using `WCSession`s  `isWatchAppInstalled` property.

Things get much trickier if you want to get the paired watch's OS version regardless of whether your app is installed. If the user runs the watch app, you could just grab the version on the watch side and send it over (with `updateApplicationContext(_:)`). Otherwise, there's no way that I know of to  get the watchOS version -- and that kind of makes sense. From a platform security perspective, if the user hasn't installed your app then the details of their watch are kind of none of your business.

Answer (score -1):

Here are two possible solutions.  Number 1 checks for the OS which if I understand your question you already know, but then 2 checks for the OS version which is WatchOS 5.0 and later.  This is what I have done so I hope it helps you.

1.

```
#if os(watchOS)
    ...your code          
#endif
```

2. ```
   if #available(watchOS 5.0, *) {
       ...your code
   }
   ```

Comment: This does not work when running in an iOS app, only when already on an installed watchOS app

Comment: Ahh, I did not think about that.  Sorry.  What if you checked the targetEnvironment, and then check the avalible OS version?  If targetEnvironment has a watchOS target.

Comment: Not sure I follow. Where/how are you checking the targetEnvironment?

Comment: I have not really used this before but I was thinking something like `#if targetEnvironment(watchOS)`.  If that is even possible with watchOS, and then inside of that you can check the version for watchOS 5.

Comment: Sorry this isn't really what I'm asking for. #if targetEnvironment is watchOS, it would need to be running on the watch. I'm looking for a check from iOS

Comment: Ok.  Sorry I could not help.